# I've finished Bioshock - now what?

Tags: bioshock

I've finished Bioshock (and loved it).

I played through with rescuing all little sisters first, then went back and harvested the 3 just before the proving grounds to see the other ending.

I may go see Sander Cohen's apartment.

**Is there anything else worth doing before I uninstall?**

I was surprised to find the game was really finished, because the Bathysphere destination choice screen had 3 or so gaps when I saw it last (am I maybe missing some areas?)

(I have to uninstall, I'm low on HDD space and want to play the next game).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go the uninstall the game. You saw both endings, you could be really picky and find all the audio logs and upgrade all weapons, however I don't think that is worth it. Seeing the two possible endings is the most important thing.

I would recommend moving onto your next game.

Comment: I loved the audio logs (mostly they had *awesome* voice acting - especially Dianne McClintock), but yeah, I think I'm just too busy to spend an hour or two hunting down the few I've missed.

Comment: I should add, if you want do to hear all the audio logs, but don't have the time to find them in the game, you *can* find them all online with a little googling.